# Use of gsub function to clean a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a column showing total assets of some people in **Rs 3,94,24,827 ~ 3 Crore+** this format. I want this column to show only numeric data i.e. 39400000 for the above value and same for every row. How to do this in R.

Comment: You have this `Rs 3,94,24,827 ~ 3 Crore+` and want this `39424827`?

Comment: Please post some data by editing the question with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`, replacing `data` by the name of your dataset. Also, in order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try something like

```
text=“Rs 3,94,24,827 ~ 3 Crore+”
gsub(“\\D”,””,gsub(“,[2].+”,”00000”,text))
[1] “39400000”
```

To obtain the number alone;

```
gsub(“(~.*)|\\D”,””,text)
[1]”39424827”
```

Comment: Looks like you pasted some fancy left and right quotes into your answer --- they'll need to be replaced with standard `"` to work in R.

Comment: I see what you mean. It’s just that I am using my phone to answer the question.

Comment: @Onyambu The solution works, but in gsub(“\\D”,””,gsub(“,[2].+”,”00000”,text)) you have hard-coded the number of zeroes to append, whereas the column which I was trying to clean contains more than 1 record. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well I hope you can use the second one and round the numeric obtained